# Excel 2016 opening files with grey sections

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Some files on Excel 2016 will sometimes open with some of the rows just showing as grey (see image). When this happens, opening the file menu will also show as completely grey. The only way to get out is to close the application. Other parts of the ribbon are not responsive. The scroll bar works though.
The file is not corrupted, as I am able to open it later and all the data is there.

[image]

The only partial correlation I found is for opening files on a remote network drive.
But it sometimes also happens for local file.

I thought this was a low resource (RAM etc) issue with the machine, but I checked the task manager and everything seems just fine.

Comment: My first impulse is that this is a rendering issue, maybe combined with network lag. Are your graphic card drivers up to date?

Comment: All excel files have this problem? How about opening in safe mode?